# android: React native open an app from another app?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to open a another app(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inova.velocity) from my app. But there are all the tutorial just redirecting url to playstore only.(I found a github link(https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link) and it opens the app for iOS only, but for Android it is redirecting to playstore). Is there is any way to solve this problem?

```
Linking.canOpenURL('market://details?id=com.inova.velocity')
      .then((canOpen) => {
        if (canOpen) { 
          console.log('open app'); 
          return Linking.openURL('market://details?id=com.inova.velocity')
                 };
        }).catch(err => console.log('An error occurred', err));
```

Comment: Is the app installed in the android device already, while you are running your code?

Comment: @Sateesh yup.. my task is have to open the app if it is installed, or open playstore.

Comment: is com.inova.velocity developed by you?

Comment: @VinayakB No.. its downloaded one.

Comment: is com.inova.velocity have any deep link associate with app?

Comment: @VinayakB don't know about that bro..  i saw a example, we can open app like whatsapp and fb. Lykwise cant we open this app?

Comment: we can open whatsapp and fb , they are provided deep link to its activities.

Comment: is it compulsory to have a deep link? i think we need deep link when we need to open a special activity(eg: sending message). otherwise we can open any app ryt?  i already tried that with native android.. I dont know how to do with react?

Comment: any update on this I have stuck badly on this please help

Comment: @Sagar find the answer below.

Comment: @Sagar find the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your code is correct. But you have used playstore url, instead of schema url.  you have to set the schemaUrl which you can get it from relevant app developer. if there is no schema url set for the that app you can't open it. after you get the SchemaUrl you can use your code. like below.

```
Linking.canOpenURL(SchemaUrl).then(supported => {
             if (supported) {
               console.log('accepted');
               return Linking.openURL(SchemaUrl);
             } else {
               console.log('an error occured');
             }
           }).catch(
             err => console.log('an error occured');
           );
```

Comment: How we can find this SchemaUrl?

Comment: SchemaUrl needs to be configure in relavant app

Comment: Can please share some doc related to this SchemaUrl?

Answer (score -1):

using [react-native-send-intent module](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent) , you can do
SendIntentAndroid.openApp('packagename').then((wasOpened) => {}); where your package name is whatever application package name you want to open.

for eg 
SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.inova.velocity').then((wasOpened) => {});

wasOpened is a Boolean promise telling you whether the app was opened or not